# How to call a function of the caller's namespace with this?

Tags: jquery, function, namespaces

Goal: I'm trying to shorten how I call a function of the same namespace in a function by using "this" instead of the namespace string. But apparently "this" wouldn't work for a function, it only works for a variable. I wish to know if it's due to my misusage, or to call function with a namespace string is the only way.

Another beginner's question: I'm calling a function of the same namespace as the caller's. I googled and someone said by calling: this.myfunction would work, but it doesn't. Any ideas? thanks.

I'm calling:
**singleEntry.editContent.accept(tinyMCE.get('editContentTa').getContent());**

from:
**index.fragment.singleEntry.editContent.load**

I've tried to do it as: this.accept, but firebug says this.accept is not a function...

```
  index.fragment.singleEntry.editContent.load = (function(singleEntry) {
return function() {
    // prepare edit dialog
    $("#editContentDiv").dialog({
        autoOpen : false,
        height : 500,
        width : 600,
        modal : true,
        buttons : {
            "OK" : function() {
                singleEntry.editContent.accept(tinyMCE.get('editContentTa').getContent());
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "CANCEL" : function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open : function() {
            // set value to the edit area
            tinyMCE.get("editContentTa").setContent($("#veContent").html());
        }
    });
```

Comment: I've verified that, for a variable, this.variableName would work. But for a function it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not *quite* following your ultimate goal, so some theory in hopes it helps you get there:

When you call a function via an object's property (so, via dotted notation, or `[]` notation), `this` within the function call will be the object reference. So when you call

```
singleEntry.editContent.accept(tinyMCE.get('editContentTa').getContent());
```

...within that call, `this` will refer to `singleEntry.editContent`.

If you want `this` to refer to something else, you can use `call`:

```
singleEntry.editContent.accept.call(thisObj, tinyMCE.get('editContentTa').getContent());
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...where `thisObj` is whatever object you want the function to see as `this` during the call. More here: *[Mythical methods](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html)*

`call` is a property of all (real) JavaScript functions, and is provide specifically to make it easy to call the function and set what `this` should be (what the *context* is) during the call. There's also `apply`, which does exactly the same thing but accepts the arguments to pass to the function as an array rather that as discrete arguments. E.g., these two calls are identical:

```
// Using `call`
singleEntry.editContent.accept.call(thisObj, tinyMCE.get('editContentTa').getContent());

// Using `apply`
singleEntry.editContent.accept.call(thisObj, [tinyMCE.get('editContentTa').getContent()]);
//                        Note the `[]` -----^
```

All of this is made possible because in JavaScript, `this` is determined entirely by *how a function is called*, not *where it's defined* — I think you know that, based on your question, but worth flagging up anyway.

Comment: thanks, TJ. Crowder. But I'm trying to shorten the way I call a function of the same namespace...

Comment: "All of this is made possible because in JavaScript, this is determined entirely by how a function is called, not where it's defined — I think you know that, based on your question, but worth flagging up anyway." Good point. It's the first time for me to know about it. :D

Comment: @Issac: JavaScript doesn't have namespaces, just objects (er, and scopes). I'm afraid I'm just not following your end goal. What object do you want to be `this`, and why? (And: Glad I included that note, then! I wasn't entirely sure, and it's sufficiently different from other languages that I try to highlight it for people.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply again! :) My goal is : I'm trying to shorten how I call a function of the same namespace in a function by using "this" instead of the namespace string. But apparently "this" wouldn't work for a function, it only works for a variable. I wish to know if it's due to my misusage, or to call function with a namespace string is the only way.

Comment: @Issac: `this.variableName` doesn't refer to a variable, it refers to a property. Functions attached to objects are also just property values, so there's no difference between them in that sense. If your goal is just to have a shorter reference to the function, that's no problem: `var x = singleEntry.editContent; x.accept(...);` And again, JavaScript doesn't have namespaces, so you may be confusing yourself using that term...

Comment: Aha, THANK YOU! Got it. I know I'm cheating myself into believing there are namespaces in JS. It just makes me feel codes in a mess without that concept....